# JabRef and entrytype @Standard

Tags: bibtex, jabref

Anyone that knows why entrytype "@Standard" does not exist in JabRef (anylonger?)?

/Lars

Comment: Did you customise the entry types? (http://help.jabref.org/en/CustomEntryTypes) Are you in BibTeX or `biblatex` mode? If you are in `biblatex` mode presumably `@standard` is not shown by default because it is (ironically given its name) a *non-standard type* that has no dedicated support by the standard styles of `biblatex` and falls back to the `@misc` bibliography style.

Comment: JabRef does not yet parse the bst file to adapt the UI accordingly. It makes assumptions based on the standard bsts. We are aware that this causes confusion, but we don't have a solution yet. Help welcome.

Comment: @moewe I have to check the link that you shared. I have to check which mode I use. How do I do that btw?

Comment: JabRef shows the mode of a `.bib` file amongst others in the title of the window "(biblatex mode)" or "(BibTeX mode)". In the *File* menu you can switch to the other mode.